# How to update value in a "Any" type Object

Tags: ios, swift

I've a big json data. I'm trying to describe the scenario below ->

```
JSON = {

"str1": 1,

"str2": false,

"response":

  {
    "str1": 10.2,

    "lists": [{
        "list": ["a", "b", "c"],
        "something": 1
    }, {
        "list": ["a1", "b1", "c1"],
        "something": 2
    }]

  }

}
```

I get this json from server as [String : Any]

```
var jsonData: Any?

func firstInitialiseJsonData(jsonData: Any?) { // Initialize jsonData by server json
     self.jsonData = jsonData
}
```

Now I want to update this self.jsonData.

```
func updateJsonData() {
     guard let newJsonData = self.jsonData as? [String : Any] else { return }
     guard let response = newJsonData["response"] as? [String : Any] else { return }
     guard var lists = response["lists"] as? [[String : Any]] else { return }

     lists.append(["list": ["a2","b2","c2"], "something" : 3])

}
```

But above code is not working, because "lists" contains copy data. How can I update self.jsonData? Any Help

Comment: What about using `Decodable`?

Comment: @Ahmad F can you elaborate?

Comment: Just take a look at vadian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53300776/5501940), he is using decodable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But above code is not working, because "lists" contains copy data. How can I update self.jsonData?

I'd do it by reassigning each of the pieces back to the container from whence they came. I don't have time to test the following code right now, so watch out for errors, but this should at least illustrate the idea:

```
func updateJsonData() {
     guard var newJsonData = self.jsonData as? [String : Any] else { return }
     guard var response = newJsonData["response"] as? [String : Any] else { return }
     guard var lists = response["lists"] as? [[String : Any]] else { return }

     lists.append(["list": ["a2","b2","c2"], "something" : 3])
     response["lists"] = lists
     newJsonData["response"] = response
     self.jsonData = newJsonData
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply. Your answer is exactly fit for me. Basically this is my office project and I can not change the whole thing like taking json as String and using decodable to extract answer

Answer (score 5):

In a value type environment you have to assign the mutated object back. This is very cumbersome when using *primitive* collection types.

With custom structs and `Decodable` it's much more convenient (and efficient)

This example omits all irrelevant keys

```
let json = """
{
    "str1": 1,
    "str2": false,
    "response": {
        "str1": 10.2,
        "lists": [{
            "list": ["a", "b", "c"],
            "something": 1
        }, {
            "list": ["a1", "b1", "c1"],
            "something": 2
        }]
    }
}
"""

struct Root : Decodable {
    var response : Response
}

struct Response : Decodable {
    var lists : [List]
}

struct List : Decodable {
    let list : [String]
    let something : Int
}
```

---

```
let data = Data(json.utf8)

do {
    // decode the JSON to the `Root` struct, `var` makes the object mutable
    var jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    // create a new `List`
    let newList = List(list: ["a2","b2","c2"], something: 3)
    // assign the value back to the top level object
    jsonData.response.lists.append(newList)

    print(jsonData)

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```